# JSP component and CSS

Tags: jsp, components

I would like to build my website from components.
Each part of website are built from one jsp tags (or just jsp page which is included from other page).
Then when I need the component, I just import jsp or just write the jsp tag.

I like this direction because it allows developers to work independently and reduce the complexity.
Components are independent. Each component has its own javascript, css and even test file.

There is only one annoything: in order to import a component to a page, I have to specify the css file, the main jsp file, include the javascript file.

Is there away to import the whole component with all related static resource just one import ?
This will definitely clean up my code.

Thank you in advance

Hai

Comment: You may mention the static resources in separate jsp and import this along with other other jsp. Mean one import will increase but it will centralize the import of static resources.

Comment: @Pradeep: Your solution does not work. The CSS has it be import in the <head> section and only one time (even if component is reused multiple time in the page)

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem. I'm also having this problem. i've got a head.jsp, which contains the html for my header and imports a css stylesheet. But when I include the head.jsp, the stylesheet import is being placed inside the body in the page I do the include :(. I've started a thread about this and there is currently a bounty on this, but still no solution that works. Maybe you can help me ;)